# Contradiction in the Media Foundation AAC specification regarding LATM/LAOS streams

Tags: ms-media-foundation

Reading the official [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742784(v=vs.85).aspx) for the ms media foundation AAC decoder there is the following section in the middle of the document:

> The AAC decoder does not support any of the following:
>
> - Main profile, Sample-Rate Scalable (SRS) profile, or Long Term    Prediction (LTP) profile.
> - Audio data interchange format (ADIF).
> - **LATM/LAOS transport streams.**
> - Coupling channel elements (CCEs). The decoder will skip audio frames    with CCEs.
> - AAC-LC with a 960-sample frame size. Only
>     1024-sample    frames are supported.

But in the beginning of the same page the following is stated:

> Starting in Windows 8, the AAC decoder also supports decoding MPEG-4
>   audio transport streams with a multiplex layer (LATM) and
>   synchronization layer (LOAS). It can also convert an LATM/LOAS stream
>   to ADTS.

I assume and am quite sure that LATM/LAOS transport streams are supported and that the part which says LATM/LAOS is not supported was simply not removed when support for it was added. **But is this assumption correct?**

What I am afraid of is that I am somehow not seeing some nuance here and that both statements are true but in different cases.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a problem with documentation update. Added new functionality, and not removed earlier limitations.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am hoping for. It sounds reasonable at least